# Why isn't StackExchange's OpenID listed in the OpenID providers?

Tags: feature-request, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

StackExchange's own OpenID provider doesn't appear in the list of quick-signin buttons:

[image]

There's clearly space, perhaps it could be added to save us [looking it up](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/) or having to type in https://openid.stackexchange.com?

Pretty please?

Comment: See those email/password fields? Those go through the SE openID behind the scenes.

Comment: It's there right in front of you: the "Email" and "Password" textboxes

Comment: D'Oh! - it's obvious now you've pointed it out.. sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees!